# How to use distinct keyword in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql, distinct

```
 String a="DISTINCT std FROM add_std";
 q = ses.createQuery(a);
 List <my.add_std>list = ses.createQuery(a).list();
```

//Error will occur if i use distinct keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here if you want it to be done by HQL then u use below code...

```
String a="DISTINCT std FROM add_std";
q = ses.createQuery(a);
q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
List <my.add_std>list = ses.createQuery(a).list();
```

else using sql u need to iterate each attribute like

```
String a="select distinct s.studentname from student s";
    ListIterator<Object[]> ObjectsIterator = session.createSQLQuery(query).list().listIterator();
    while (ObjectsIterator.hasNext())
    {
     Object object = (Object) ObjectsIterator.next();
     String name = (String) object;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but again it'll show the error.

Comment: Issue: java.lang.String cannot be cast to my.add_std